# python error trying to split book into chapters

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from urllib.request import urlopen

#Reading the text of novel from a website
huck_fin_url = 'http://www.gutenberg.org/files/76/76-0.txt'
df = urlopen(huck_fin_url)
huck_fin_text = df.read()
#print(huck_fin_text)
huck_fin_chapters = huck_fin_text.split('CHAPTER ')[1:]
```

**Error**

> File "/Users/richxxxxx/Documents/ReadBooks.py", line 19, in 
>       huck_fin_chapters = huck_fin_text.split('CHAPTER ')[1:]
>
> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urlopen` returns a byte stream rather than a string, and `.split()` isn't available to those objects. You'll need to decode it based on the correct character set first:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

#Reading the text of novel from a website
huck_fin_url = 'http://www.gutenberg.org/files/76/76-0.txt'
df = urlopen(huck_fin_url)
huck_fin_text = df.read().decode("utf8")
#print(huck_fin_text)
huck_fin_chapters = huck_fin_text.split('CHAPTER ')[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen

huck_fin_url = 'http://www.gutenberg.org/files/76/76-0.txt'  
df = urlopen(huck_fin_url)  
huck_fin_text = str(df.read())
huck_fin_chapters = huck_fin_text.split('CHAPTER ')[1:]  
print(huck_fin_chapters)
```

you have to add 'str' front of df.read()